# Method is not doing what it's expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to execute a query in a MSSQL stored procedure, to do this I use, javascript, ajax and C#, here is my code (javascript and ajax are just to send parameter to my C# WebService and works fine, the problem is with my db method or my webservice code):

`WebService`

```
[WebMethod]
public string RegistrarInspeccion(int id, string partNumber, string inspectionDate, string data, string data2, int newId)
{
   string respuesta = "Error";

   try
   {
       Inspection ins = new Inspection(id, partNumber, inspectionDate, data, data2, newId);
       int resp = conn.RegistrarInspeccion(ins);

       if (resp > 0)
          respuesta = "Good Job";
       else
          respuesta = "Something happen ....";
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      respuesta = "Error: " + ex.Message;
   }
    return respuesta;
}
```

`DB_Class`

```
public int RegistrarInspeccion(Inspection ins)
{
   int res = 0;
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertInspection", conn);
   try
   {
     Open();
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partNumber", ins.PartNumber);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inspectionDate", ins.InspectionDate);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", ins.Data);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data2", ins.Data2);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewId", ins.NewId);

     res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   }

   finally
   {
      Close();
   }
   return res;    
}
```

I don't get any error, just I always get the "respuesta = `"Something happen ....";` message, I don't have any idea of what could be the problem, maybe my db code is not been executed correctly? What can I do to fix this? Thanks in advance.

I tried to change `respuesta = "Something happen ....";` to `respuesta = resp.toString();` and now I'm getting -1 as result.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see what happens in your `try` block?  Have you examined the SQL being sent to the DB and tried running in SSMS (or the equivalent if you're not using SQL Server)?

Answer (score 0):

Check your SQL, from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.**

Comment: No, -1 means that you are not inserting any rows, or there's been a roll back.

Comment: Right now I looked my database and there are all my tries to insert information, so all my code works perfect, just that if that I mentioned